# How to solve AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim'?

Tags: python

I want to test my keras model. But I've faced that problem. I have an image for checking in the "path".

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\Администратор\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\577793008_ef4345205b.jpg'

model = keras.models.load_model('C:\\Users\\Администратор\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\model1.h5')
predictions = model.predict(path)
print (predictions[0])
```

Error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\load1.p
y", line 11, in <module>
    predictions = model.predict(path)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1441, in predict
    x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(x)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 579, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 99, in standardize_input_data
    data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 99, in <listcomp>
    data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 34, in standardize_single_array

    elif x.ndim == 1:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Comment: You are not supposed to pass the `path` to the `model.predict()` method. Just run `model.predict()` and it should work

Comment: From the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict): *"`predict(x, ...)` - `x`: Input samples. It could be:
__A Numpy array__ (or array-like), or a list of arrays (in case the model has multiple inputs).
__A TensorFlow tensor__, or a list of tensors (in case the model has multiple inputs).
__A tf.data dataset__.
__A generator or keras.utils.Sequence instance__"*. But it cannot be a string...

Answer (score 0):

The `predict` method can take several types of inputs, but not a string. It cannot directly read a file based on the path.

You need to transform this file into whatever can be read by the [`Model` class](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict). Read the file and make the content an array for instance.

Comment: I'll check out. Thanks!